# How to Preprocess xml fields when using Javax @XmlElement for reading properties

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, xml-parsing

I have properties.xml in the Spring boot project as follow:

```
...
<RestConnect>
    <Name>OpenBanking</Name>
    <RestEnable>true</RestEnable>
    <IP>192.168.11.11</IP>
    <Port>3311</Port>
</RestConnect>
...
```

and corresponding java file is :

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RestConnectProperties {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private String name = "Unknown";

    @XmlElement(name = "RestEnable")
    private boolean restEnable = true;

    @XmlElement(name = "IP")
    private String ip = "";

    @XmlElement(name = "Port")
    private String port = "";


    public RestConnectProperties() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isRestEnable() {
        return restEnable;
    }

    public void setRestEnable(boolean restEnable) {
        this.restEnable = restEnable;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public String getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(String port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

}
```

it sets values correctly into related fields.

I want to preprocess on fields.
For example, I want to check if IP has entered correctly, or I want to Uppercase the 'Name', then set them into object fields. How can I do it?

Comment: i think you can do that in setter method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, move the `@XmlElement` / `@XmlAttribute` annotations to the getter methods.

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) // ONLY PROCESS ANNOTATED FIELDS/PROPERTIES
public class RestConnectProperties {
    . . .

    // REMOVE THIS: @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private String name = "Unknown";

    . . .

    @XmlElement(name = "Name") // ADD HERE
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name.toUpperCase(); // PROCESS HERE
    }

    . . .
}
```

I prefer changing [`@XmlAccessorType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessorType.html) to [`XmlAccessType.NONE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType.html#NONE), so only explicitly annotated fields and/or property getter/setter methods are used by JAXB.

You can of course keep using [`XmlAccessType.FIELD`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType.html#FIELD), but then you'd have to add [`@XmlTransient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) to the field, so you can switch from field-based to property-based handling by JAXB.

Comment: Thank you Andreas, your answer partially solved my issue, but still I have a problem with Boolean field.
When I put “tRUE” or “tRuE” in xml field, it set ‘False’ for the corresponding Boolean field in java object. For example:
    <RestEnable>tRUE</RestEnable>
How can I preprocess this field in order to use “equalsIgnoreCase” method, so that it set value to be “true”?

Comment: @SM.Hosseini XML [specifies](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean) that `boolean` value must be `"true"`, `"false"`, `"1"`, or `"0"`. JAXBs parser is lenient, parsing any other value as `false`, relying on schema validation to reject bad values. Don't attempt to fix bad data, reject it, by enabling schema validation.